# How to store data more than 255 character in access 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access-2013

i have the data more than 255 character, so how to store it because in access the limit is 255.I have try to change the data type to long text but it still have problem.

Answer (score 2):

long text should be enough, this is the Microsoft description of short text and long text, depending on your access db type (note the comments re the 64000 character display limit in controls in .accdb, is this your issue?)-

> Text fields in desktop databases (.accdb)
>
> Long Text    In .accdb files, the Long Text field works the same as the Memo field of old. That is, it can store up to about a gigabyte of text, even though controls on forms and reports can only display the first 64,000 characters. You can set Long Text fields to display Rich Text, which includes formatting like bold and underline.
>
> Short Text    In .accdb files, the Short Text field works the same as the Text field in earlier versions. It stores up to 255 characters.
>
> Text fields in Access web apps
>
> Long Text    In Access web apps, the Long Text field can store up to 2^30-1 >bytes, and is equivalent to the SQL Server data type of nvarchar(max). If you want, you can set a character limit to prevent your users from using the full capacity of the field. You can’t store Rich Text in Access web apps.
>
> Short Text    In Access web apps the Short Text field is set to store 255 characters by default, but you can adjust the Character Limit property all the way up to 4000 characters. Its SQL Server equivalent is nvarchar, with length from 1 to 4000.

Comment: Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/datatype-property?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Funny though: I have the same issue and "long text" can only hold 255

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Text Format` to `Rich Text` in the **Design View Property Sheet** for each control bound to a Long Text (Memo) field. By default it is set to Plain Text which effectively limits the input to 255 characters.

Answer (score -2):

just make your type to TEXT. it can store unlimited characters (well as long as your hard drive can handle it)

Comment: what do you mean by text? @Emil

Comment: make the data type to TEXT.

Comment: There is no such thing in MS Access. It only has "short text" or "long text"